# Different Hover Messages for Different Portions of the Same Edit Link

Tags: feature-request, tooltips

This is incredibly trivial but still hung me up for about 5 minutes trying to figure it out.

### Meet Mr. Revision Link

> [image: Hover Link]

He looks innocent, but he is hiding two dark secrets.

### What's the Time Mr. Revision Link?

> [image: This is Not the Time]

That isn't the time! But all other links show me the time when they hover! Why do you tease me so? Let's try that again.

### I Won't Ask Again!

> [image: This is the Time]

Both links lead to the same place. Yet depending on which bit you hover, you get different messages. Wouldn't it be swell to eliminate any chance of confusion as follows?

### Who is Your Timestamp and What Does He Do?

> [image: Make Love, Not Confusion]

Ta-da! Problem solved. Solved even better if I knew how to make it two lines, but it is probably best to leave something for the professionals to do.

<sup>Alternatively, just make the timestamp hover work for the 'edited' portion too, if nobody actually needs to be told where the link goes</sup>

### Addendum

When you browse a tag. The circled portion has no timestamp (but I expect it to):

> [image: Same Story, Different 画面]

Comment: I don't like combining them. When I hover over a time, I expect to see a timestamp, and *only* a timestamp. If two different tooltips is bothersome to people, I'd recommend just removing the "show all edits to this post" tooltip.

Comment: @animuson I'm fine with that too. Either way. I was expecting the timestamp, but figured that maybe there are new users who don't know where the link goes without hover text.

Comment: Wow never noticed this... and I usually notice such things! :)